# Magento: How to enable/disable module output per website level?

Tags: magento

I would like to **display an image in the onepage checkout payment methods section that would only show up in one of two website levels**. So I have three questions:

**1)** Am I correct to assume this change would be coded in app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/checkout.xml ?

**2)** if that is the correct file, what would the change be from:

```
<!--
One page checkout payment methods block
-->
    <checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
        <remove name="left"/>

        <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
            <action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </checkout_onepage_paymentmethod>
```

in order to point to, for example, checkout/onepage/payment/methods-site2.phtml when site2 is being used?

**3)** Is this the proper way to do this in 1.5.x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. You need add STORE_[your_store_code] handle and put there this store specific stuff. More info you can read in this [article](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/digging-deeper-into-magentos-layout-xml-part-2/).
   So, in your case, you need update block with name root. To change block template you need some method for this, let's say its name is `setTemplate`. So, in your layout update file you should write

```xml
<STORE_your_code>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/onepage/payment/methods-site2.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="my_cool/block" name="my_cool_block">
        ...
        </block>
    </reference>
</STORE_your_code>
```

3. Yes, adding store specific handle to your theme layout update file is the right way for magento CE 1.5.x.

Comment: 2. the linked article, although very informative, does not mention how to add a block that would be output only for a certain store.

Comment: I still dont know where to apply the code because element nesting rules  are not specified. I tried the following and it did not work:

Comment: `<checkout_op>
<remove name="left"/>

<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
<action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/po.phtml</template></action>
</block>

<STORE_pt>
<block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="root" output="toHtml" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods_pt.phtml">
<action method="setMethodFormTemplate"><method>purchaseorder</method><template>payment/form/po.phtml</template></action>
</block>
</STORE_pt> 
</checkout_op>`

Comment: Nooo, `<STORE_your_code>` is handle, not block. It should be outside of your action handle `<checkout_op>`, on the same level where all your other handles are.

Comment: So it is OK to have two <checkout_op> handles, except that one is wrapped in <STORE_your_code> and the other isn't?

Comment: No, `<STORE_your_code>` is handle, you should use `<reference name="block_a">` inside this handle to switch context to the context of needed block `block_a` and then do store specific things (add/remove `block_a` child blocks, etc.). `block_a` may be defined in your `<checkout_op>` handle or anywhere else but visible for current request. Does it make sense now?

Comment: The code in the original question is the actual code for the block that needs to be switched (swapping <checkout_onepage_paymentmethod> for <checkout_op>).
I have a hard time believing I can remove a block named "root" without specifying it is the block named "root" from inside handle "<checkout_op>", which you did not instruct me to do.

Comment: I am willing to learn and ready to work on this for another week, thank you. But wouldn't it be easier if you just rewrote the original code to include a store switched block along with the original one??